# On Solaris, can I alias one command to multiple possible locations?

Tags: solaris, alias

Let's say I have a script called `bob`. It might be in two locations: `/usr/local/bin/bob` or `/usr/local/bin/scripts/bob`. Is there a way I can alias `bob` to both locations and it will stop whenever it finds `bob`? So if `bob` is in `/usr/local/bin/bob`, it will stop there, otherwise it will look in `/usr/local/bin/scripts/bob`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what your PATH environment variable is for.

Arrange your PATH environment variable so that both locations are on the path, AND in the order you want them to to be checked.

So in your example, `/usr/local/bin` should be earlier in the PATH than `/usr/local/bin/scripts`.

Most systems will probably have `/usr/local/bin` already in the system path, so you'll only need to add the second location to your shell startup scripts.  If you're using `bash`, this command would do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/scripts
```

Other shells will vary.

Comment: +1: Exactly what I came in here to say. Bin directories are a good place to store commands anyway; rather than putting your script directory in the path, you might want to put links to your script commands in the bin directory...But that's a personal preference.